# Collections in C#

Tags: c#, collections

am converting a vb.net component to c#, i get this error

`Using the generic type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>' requires '1' type argument`s

This is what i did

in VB.NET i had this

```
 Private _bufferCol As Collection
```

i did this in c#

```
private Collection _bufferCol = new Collection();
```

My declaration is

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasi;    
using System.Collections;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.ComponentModel;    
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
```

Can any body help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a Type declaration fro your collection.  That is, what type is your collection holding?

For instance:

```
//strings
private Collection<string> _bufferCol = new Collection<string>();
```

Comment: this is an object collection. am using it to hold winsock collection

Comment: @Oghenero: as @Cacek said in his comment, just substitute your correct object type (Socket, I believe in this case) where I have 'string'.

Comment: What would be a good alternative to `Collection<T>` in immutable format (besides `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`)? I'm looking for a ready to use implementation of a collection with a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`, and add some additional filtering and organization features.

Answer (score 10):

It's confused because there is a type named "Collection" in both the Microsoft.VisualBasic and the System.Collections.ObjectModel namespaces.  You can fix things for a direct translation like this:

```
private Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection _buffer = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection();
```

But I don't recommend doing that.  The Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace is intended mainly for easier migration away from older vb6-era code.  You really shouldn't use it's Collection type any more.

Instead, adapt this code to use a generic `List<T>` or `Collection<T>`.

Comment: This. The C# compiler is expecting the `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` class, and Oghenero is (apparently) trying to use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection`.

Comment: Beat me to the punch!
@Oghenero - Yes, it's a namespace problem, but also you probably shouldn't use the MS.VB.Collection anyways and choose a specific generic one instead.

Comment: Error

The type or namespace name 'Collection' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Oghenero Make sure you reference the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly in your project.  The collection class in there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.aspx  Or even better, read the more important part of my post and _don't_ reference that assembly.

Comment: @Joel - For most practical purposes, when developing in VB you can't avoid using  the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace.  VB doesn't have `\t`, `\n` and `\r` line C#, so you're stuck with vbTab, vbLf, vbCr, and vbCrLf.  Yes, you could type `System.Environment.Newline` everywhere or make up your own constants, but that's borderline masochistic.  You can't even make your own tab constant with Chr(9), because `Chr()` is in that namespace.  The better advice is include it, but limit usage to only the parts where there's no better alternative, meaning avoid string functions like `Trim()`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As it says, you need to specify the type of objects stored in collection.

When you have:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>
```

this `T` means the type of your objects in collection.

If you need to accept all types of objects, just use

```
var _bufferCol = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<object>();
```

Comment: this is an object collection. am using it to hold winsock collection

Comment: @Oghenero - winsock collection? So what is the type of this "winsock"? Just put it instead of T in the code and it should work for you

Comment: i wrote a winsock component in vb.net . i want to convert it to c#. i use the collection to store collections or the component in case there is more that one. should i post the class file instead?

Comment: No. When you will rewrite your winsock component to C# and i.e. you will call the class implementing it `WinSock`, then just use `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<WinSock>` as your collection (or even better, `List<WinSock>`)

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to [use a typed collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx?ppud=4) in C# but not specifying the type.

Try

```
private Collection<MyType> _bufferCol = new Collection<MyType>();
```

Where MyType is the type of the thing you want to put in the collection.

C# allows you to strongly type collections, lists, sets, etc so that the kind of thing they contain is known and can be checked at compile time.

Comment: this is an object collection. am using it to hold winsock collection